# How to reinstate rollbacked changes in TFS

Tags: tfs

**Here's the scenario:**

- I made changes to the codebase that brought it to changeset 10.
- I rolled back changeset 10 such that changeset 11 is a rollback of 10.
- Changes other people made brought the codebase up to changeset 20.

Now I'm interested in reinstating the changes I made in changeset 10.

**Question:** What's the best way to do this in TFS 2012?

**Things I've tried:** Creating a branch from changeset 10, then trying to merge it back into the main branch. TFS says there are no changes to merge.

P.S. Assume the changes in changeset 10, and the changes up to changeset 20, are across tens to hundreds of files, so a relatively automatic solution is best here.

Answer (score 0):

Open up a command prompt in the root directory of your team project

> tf difference /version:c9~C10 . /recursive /format:unified

Then checkout your entire project (only needed if you're using server workspaces)

Use a 3rd party tool to apply the unified diff, unfortunately the built in one doesn't seem to support applying diffs.

Review your changes, if needed you can run the following command to undo checkout on files you haven't edited

> tfpt uu /noget

Answer (score 0):

Use `get specific version` to get version 10.
Check out the files (make sure you still have v10).
`Get latest version` to merge the changes.
Check in.

If the above fails, then you may need to do an extra step to ensure you have the right version:
Get specific version, v10
Backup the files
Check out
Restore your backup
Get latest, merge, check in.

Another option is to get history on the files in the changeset, and (file by file) do a diff between the two versions (just select any two versions in the history and then compare then from the context menu). Then manually apply the necessary changes to recover the v10 behaviour. This can be an easier approach if the changes were small.